# Importing specific items with namespace

Tags: python, python-import

I want to import specific items from a module - only those that are needed and not all items of that module - but want to preserve the module's namespace, i.e. maintain the module name as "prefix" to access these items. In other words, use best of both the `import module` and `from module import item` constructs.

Is there a simpler/better construct to achieve this, instead of doing the following (which is a lot of code, looks somewhat clumsy and still leaves unnecessary symbols in the global namespace)?

```
from types import ModuleType
from myModule import Item1, Item2

myModule = ModuleType("myModule")
myModule.Item1 = Item1
myModule.Item2 = Item2
```

Comment: What do you see as the benefit of this? All names are actually loaded either way.

Comment: You mean the benefit of only importing the items that are needed instead of doing an "import myModule"? To my view it is better to explicitly indicate your dependencies. Although the module might be loaded completely, when using the "from" construction then only the selected items are usable in that context.

Comment: I mean the benefit of doing something that will make everyone else reading your code think *"why are you doing that?"* Given that each module is loaded once, completely, and that you can choose to make the whole module available or select names to be directly available (or both), what's the point of this halfway house where your intention (*"I'm importing `foo` but I'm only going to use `foo.bar`"*) is clear from reading the code anyway?

Comment: I recognize that by doing something like indicated in my original post, it would raise the question as you mentioned ("why are you doing that?"). But this example is just for illustration. I am looking for construct that would avoid this question.

Comment: The point of what you call "halfway house" is to have best of both approaches. Both approaches have their reason of being I guess. To my view the good thing of the "import" construct is that it maintains the namespace explicitly. The good thing of the "from" is that you can explicitly state what you need. With the "import" you also automatically get all items that the imported module imported. So the imported module is implicitly "dealing" its own dependencies to you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use:

```
from types import ModuleType as MT
from myModule import Item1 as It1, Item2 as It2

myModule = MT("myModule")
It1 = Item1
It2 = Item2
```

Comment: @pfp.meijers: it's not what you ask for?

Comment: Indeed. I want to access the item with the module name in front - preferably also not having the item available in the global name space. So I should be able to use myModule.Item1 and Item1 (standalone) should not be allowed (available).

Comment: @pfp.meijers. You said it's clumsy but you want to maintain module as prefix. You want to use module class but don't want to charge the global name space… I can't help.